# If Method calls are dynamically binded then why the Compiler complains The method xyz is undefined for the type xxx

Tags: java, inheritance

**If Method calls are dynamically binded then why the Compiler complains**

**The method run() is undefined for the type B**

Why is compiler checking for the presence of method run in Class b

Here is the code

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        B a = new A(); 
          a.run();//compiler complains at this line.
        a.p(10);  
        a.p(10.0); 
    } 
} 
    class B { 
        public void p(int i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i*2); 
        } 
    }

    class A  extends B{ 
        public void p(int i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
        public void run(){

        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look on my pretty simple answer that can help you to sort things out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is by design a **statically typed** language, meaning that **the compiler must know and be able to guarantee** that an implementation of that method exists in every concrete object. (Maxim Shoustin's answer very nicely demonstrates the reason behind this design decision with an example.)

If the compiler were to assume without any guarantees that an unknown object will happen to have a specific method, it would make Java a duck typed language. This could have its own advantages, but it wasn't in accordance with the design goals of Java.

In practice, in statically typed languages, virtual (meaning non-final) methods (such as your `run()` method) are resolved dynamically but the strategy used to resolve them is still written at compile time. That strategy may, for example, involve reading the correct offset of the vTable (a table containing the addresses of the actual implementations of the virtual methods of that object), in many implementations of polymorphism - leveraging the type safety of the language to gain some performance during the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Could not understand your answer .What are virtual methods and vTable?If possible elaborate please.

Answer (score 2):

#### The method run() is undefined for the type B

The error is self explanatory. The type `B` doesn't have a method called `.run()`

`B a = new A()` means that your variable `a` is of type `B` and that is all the system knows about the variable `a`.

If you did `Object s = new String()` and then did `s.toLowerCase()` it would fail as well, because the variable `s` is of type `Object` not of type `String`.

whatever type your variable is, is the only behaviors that you can call on that type.

Answer (score 2):

Its easy to show:

Let me change your code a bit:

- B = Animal
- A = Cow

after replace:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        Animal a = new Cow(); 
          a.sayMooo();//compiler complains at this line. You try to animal to say "moo"?
          a.speed(10);  
          a.speed(10.0); 
    } 
} 
    class Animal { 
        public void speed(int i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i*2); 
        } 
    }

    class Cow  extends Animal{ 
        public void p(int i) 
        { 
            System.out.println(i); 
        } 
        public void sayMooo(){

        }
    }
```

**Not all animals are Cows**

and sure

**Not all animals say "mooo"**

but

**all Cows are animals**